# Apart from mirrors, what other feedback mechanisms can you think of in a semiconductor laser

Tags: semiconductor-physics, laser

Today, I was asked by my professor this question. I was unable to answer it but I am curious to know about this.

Apart from mirrors, what other feedback mechanisms can you think of in a semiconductor laser.

Now, I was unable to think of any feedback mechanism other than the mirror which anyone studying about lasers would already know. Anyone with any Idea of this?

Comment: A quick check of any introduction to waveguide lasers will answer this. Not all semiconductor lasers are waveguide lasers, but for the ones that are, there are a few options. We usually think of mirrors as a thin reflective metal film on a flat surface, but if you only have one wavelength to worry about, you can also imagine using a multilayer dielectric mirror where each layer with a small index difference reflects a few percent but since they are regularly spaced the reflections add coherently. Then you can think about how to implement that periodic modulation in the context of a waveguide.

Comment: I would read about "introduction to waveguide lasers". Any resource where I can read about this in detail? (If you may have)

Comment: Try [The waveguide laser: A review](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226336735_The_waveguide_laser_A_review), and if that isn't enough, type "waveguide laser feedback" into a google search (search images or text or YouTube).